# how to get <a href='callto:'+phone+'> from infowindow to mysql

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, infowindow

I am trying to get a variable from the infowindow to mysql.

I have 3 links within the infowindow

1-callto
2-mail
3-web visit

```js
downloadUrl("gen_xml.php", function(data) {
        var xml = parseXml(data);
        var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
        for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
          var nombre = markers[i].getAttribute("nombre");
    var empresa = markers[i].getAttribute("empresa");
          var address = markers[i].getAttribute("address");
    var web = markers[i].getAttribute("web");
    var telefono = markers[i].getAttribute("telefono");
    var emailcontact = markers[i].getAttribute("emailcontact");

var html ="<div class='infobas'><div><a href='https://mndesign.es' alt='mndesign' target='_blank'><img src='/img/mndesign_localizatuempleo.png' width='80' height='60' style='float:left;'></a></div><div><div><strong>Contacto: </strong>" + nombre + "</div><div><strong>Empresa: </strong>" + empresa + "</div></div></div><br><div><div>" + address + "</div></div><br><div><div id='botones'><a id='visitweb' class='visitweb' href='" +web+ "' target='_blank'><span style='background: url(/img/link.png) no-repeat 1px center; padding:2px 25px 2px 25px; width:20px; height:20px;'>Web</span></a><a id='tfno' class='tfno' onclick='saveData()' href='callto:0034" + telefono + "'><span style='background: url(/img/llamar.png) no-repeat 1px center; padding:2px 20px 2px 30px; width:20px; height:20px;'>Llamar</span></a><a id='correo' class='correo' href='mailto:" + emailcontact + "?&subject=CV a traves de www.localizatuempleo.com!&body=Estimad@ " + nombre + ": Le envio CV por oferta de empleo anunciada en localizatuempleo.com!'><span style='background: url(/img/cv.png) no-repeat 1px center; padding:2px 25px 2px 25px; width:20px; height:20px;'>Enviar CV</span></a></div>></div>";
 
          var icon = customIcons[type] || {};
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: point,
   title: address +' / '+ ciudad,
            icon: icon.icon
          });
          
          function bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoBox, html) {
      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        infoBox.setContent(html);
        infoBox.open(map, marker); 
  infobox.draw(); // to redraw if infobox size changed
      });

    }
          
           function saveData() {
  var telefono = document.getElementById('tfno').getElementsByTagName('a').href;
  var url = "dataWindow.php?href=" + telefono;   
  
  downloadUrl(url, function(data, responseCode) {
    if (responseCode == 200 && data.length <= 1) {
      //document.getElementById("tfno").innerHTML = "";
    }       
  });
}
```

within the infowindow I have:

```html
<a id='tfno' class='tfno' onclick='saveData()' href='callto:0034" + telefono + "'><span style='background: url(/img/llamar.png) no-repeat 1px center; padding:2px 20px 2px 30px; width:20px; height:20px;'>Llamar</span></a>
```

is what I'm trying to get the variable in href and pass it to mysql, but the phone, this case comes empty, i need to get +telefono+.

so does the other 2 variables.

How I can get these variables?

Thanks for your help in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem, only i change the function saveData ()

```
function saveData() {
```

var telefono=document.getElementById('tfno').getAttribute('title');

$.ajax({
           url:"dataWindow.php",
        type:'POST',
        data:{phone:telefono}

```
});
```

}

and add to my link a title with getAttribute()

```
<a id='tfno' class='tfno' title='getAttribute()" + telefono + "' onclick='saveData()' href='callto:" + telefono + "'><span style='background: url(/img/llamar.png) no-repeat 1px center; padding:2px 20px 2px 30px; width:20px; height:20px;'>Llamar</span></a>
```

Now work, the only problem in my mysql a get getAttribute()111111111